# custom form control does not trigger any validation using NgControl and addValidators Function

Tags: angular, angular-forms, controlvalueaccessor, angular-controlvalueaccessor

I'm trying to learn about different ways to create custom form control using angular 13.

I've watched the Angular Connect 2017 video regarding angular forms from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8 and tried to implement and custom form control with validators.

i have a form with email and password, i created a custom control for the email,
and none of the validations that i configured are being triggered (`required` and `email`)

the custom form element is called `app-tuxin-form-email-input` that contains it's own form using a form builder.

this is the class:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Self, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ControlValueAccessor, FormBuilder, FormGroup,
   NgControl,
  Validators
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tuxin-form-email-input',
  templateUrl: './tuxin-form-email-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tuxin-form-email-input.component.scss'],
})
export class TuxinFormEmailInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {

  newChildForm: FormGroup;

  onChange = (email: string) => {};

  onTouched = () => {};

  touched = false;

  disabled = false;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, @Self() public controlDir: NgControl) {
    controlDir.valueAccessor=this;
    this.newChildForm = this.fb.group({
      email: [''],
    });
  }

  writeValue(email: string) {
    this.newChildForm.get('email')?.setValue(email, { emitEvent: false });
  }

  registerOnChange(onChange: any) {
    this.onChange = onChange;
  }

  registerOnTouched(onTouched: any) {
    this.onTouched = onTouched;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const control = this.controlDir.control;
    const validators = [Validators.required, Validators.email];
    if (control) {
      if (control.validator) {
        validators.unshift(control.validator);
      }
      control.setValidators(validators);
      control.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
  }

  setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
    this.disabled = disabled;
    disabled ? this.newChildForm.disable() : this.newChildForm.enable();
  }

}
```

and this is the template:

```
<div [formGroup]="newChildForm">
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="email" formControlName="email"
  (blur)="onTouched()" (input)="onChange($any($event.target).value)" [disabled]="disabled"
  />
  <mat-error i18n *ngIf="controlDir && controlDir.hasError('required')">Email is required</mat-error>
  <mat-error i18n *ngIf="controlDir && controlDir.hasError('email')">Email Invalid</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
</div>
```

so unfortunately none of the validators errors are being triggers and i can't understand why.

I created a stackblitz for that at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2s36qf?file=src/app/app.module.ts

any ideas regarding this issue would be greatly apprecaited.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) object on your child component, and it makes it easier to use `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` when you do so.

Also the registration of events have a callback which needs to be called for the outer form to be notified of the form changes

I [forked your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gsfzl7) and adjusted it accordingly.

The main changes were to:

1. add the forwardRef:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tuxin-form-email-input',
  templateUrl: './my-comp.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => TuxinFormEmailInputComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class TuxinFormEmailInputComponent
```

2. to have the formControl for the email available as a variable
3. and to adjust callbacks to the event registration methods `registerOnChange` and `registerOnTouched`

Comment: when I just click submit the required error does not appear on the email, is that fixable ?

Comment: thanks...  what i was trying to do is to add the default validators in the component itself, not outside of it in the main one that uses it